# Multiple Rotating Title Script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I have a HTML/CSS/JS script that is allowing me to rotate text for a certain part of it. I'm just having the problem of making it work for multiple sections as the script targets a span[data-up] & span[data-show].

Any help appreciated, code shown below.

```
<section class="rotating-text-section">
  <h2>
  We educate by
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span data-up>teaching.</span>
    <span data-show>showing.</span>
    <span>doing.</span>
    <span>repeating.</span>
  </div>
</h2>
</section>

setInterval(() => {
  const up = document.querySelector('span[data-up]');
  const show = document.querySelector('span[data-show]');
  const down = show.nextElementSibling || document.querySelector('span:first-child');

  up.removeAttribute('data-up');
  show.removeAttribute('data-show');
  show.setAttribute('data-up', '');
  down.setAttribute('data-show', '');

}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the class names of each span element and targeted them by this in the JavaScript script.

My second snippet of HTML was:

```
<div class="wrapper-two">
  <span class="second-span" data-up>technology.</span>
  <span class="second-span" data-show>experience.</span>
  <span class="second-span">listening.</span>
  <span class="second-span">experimenting.</span>
</div>
```

My second JS script is as follows:

```
setInterval(() => {
  const up = document.querySelector('.second-span[data-up]');
  const show = document.querySelector('.second-span[data-show]');
  const down = show.nextElementSibling || 
  document.querySelector('.second-span:first-child');

  up.removeAttribute('data-up');
  show.removeAttribute('data-show');
  show.setAttribute('data-up', '');
  down.setAttribute('data-show', '');

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.